# Running python on trying version without installing

Tags: python

I have some problems with my computer. Temporarily, I will have to boot ubuntu from a USB drive (trying version without installing) until I repair my computer. How must I define the path so I am able to run python scripts with matplotlib? I tried to define `PYTHONPATH=${PYTHONPATH}:/usr/lib/python3.5` then I also add python3 and python2.7. But I got some errors from the folder python 3.5

```
File "/usr/lib/python3.5/site.py", line 182
file=sys.stderr)
SyntaxError : invalid syntax
```

Any idea? thank you!

Comment: Have you actually mounted the original system device? Probably the simplest thing would be to install the relevant matplotlib package(s) (`python-matplotlib` or `python3-matplotlib`) within the USB live system

Comment: Also, have you tried simply running `/usr/bin/python3` without setting the `PYTHONPATH`? If it fails, what error do you get?

Comment: steeldriver :  I didn't exactly mount it, but the computer see my hard disk on which is my home but not my SSD disk(where are the booting files...). This is why I boot from a USB key and installing linux on  my computer is pretty hard.  I can't use the usual interface without having kernel problems. I did it once before. I had to change manually a few options before installing, but I will install only once I resolve my SSD disk problem. I will try to install it again later. It did not work well last time I tried.

Comment: MiniQuark : It does not work.  ImportError: No module named 'matplotlib'

Answer (score 0):

Getting a `SyntaxError` on that particular line certainly means that you are running Python 2 instead of Python 3 (since this is valid Python 3 syntax, but invalid Python 2).

Make sure that you are running the `python3` command rather than `python`.

**Edit**

Regarding the matplotlib loading issue, Python looks for dynamic linked libraries using paths listed in LD_LIBRARY_PATH. Make sure LD_LIBRARY_PATH includes /usr/local/lib, and try again.

Comment: I tried but it did not work. It can't find matplotlib.

Comment: It must be looking for the system libraries, I'm guessing you need to give it the paths to the dynamic libraries.  Please provide the error messages, otherwise it's hard to help you.